# Why AttributeError occurs in DataFrame.apply() but not in individual function call?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function `find_country_from_connection_ip` which basically takes a pandas Series and after processing returns a country.

```
def find_country_from_connection_ip(ip):
    final_output = None
    result = subprocess.Popen("mmdblookup --file GeoIP2-Country.mmdb --ip {} country names en".format(ip).split(" "), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
    if result:
        final_output =  result
    else:
        final_output = subprocess.Popen("mmdblookup --file GeoIP2-Country.mmdb --ip {} registered_country names en".format(ip.iloc[0]).split(" "), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()

    return re.search(r'\"([\w\s]+)\"', final_output).group(1)
```

What I am trying to do is to form a new column on my DataFrame with the return value of the above function. My attempt is:

```
dataframe_without_connection_ips['Country'] =
             dataframe_without_connection_ips.apply(lambda x:find_country_from_connection_ip(x['Connection IP']), axis=1)
```

But, The error I am getting is:

> AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'", u'occurred at index 303449')

So, my understanding says that may be error is generated from `index` 303449. So, I tried to call the function with that particular index.

```
test_ip = dataframe_without_connection_ips[dataframe_without_connection_ips.index== 303449]['Connection IP']
find_country_from_connection_ip(test_ip)
```

And, surprisingly I am getting the expected output `'United Kingdom'` without error.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way the function is applied over rows, the input to the function is string. However, in the function there is this operation

```
ip.iloc[0]
```

which seems to assume that the input is a Series or DataFrame. This explains the error message.

In your subsequent test, the input to the function actually becomes a Series, which is why the `iloc` indexing does not fail.

Comment: Okay, but see,  `ip.iloc[0]` is in `else` clause. It will only get executed, when the argument `ip` is not a string and so, `result` is evaluated to `False`. So, I have already handled the case that in else clause, I must have a Series. Am I wrong?

Comment: Could it be that in some cases ``result`` evaluates to ``False`` even if it is a string (e.g. an unexpected IP address causing the lookup in the external program to fail)?